Opera Dev Tools sidebar does not resize the new page
I used opera. it is a Chromium-based browser and I found an issue that bothers me. The Dev Tools sidebar does not resize the new page, it layers above it (see this picture)

To fix it, we have to:

resize a bit the devtools to re-trigger the responsiveness calculations
or reopen dev tools
What should have looked like


For me, it is annoying cause it happens when I change/redirect through subdomains of my website during development. Since this is based on chromium, is there any configuration or tweak that we can do to fix this issue? oh, I use Opera on Ubuntu.
